# Can you get the individual Latitude and Longitude Values from BingMapsRESTToolkit.Location?

Tags: c#, bing-maps

I was wondering if it was possible to get the individual Lat and Long number values that make up a `BingMapsRESTToolkit.Location`, and store them as their own number variables. As in something like this:

`double Latitude = Location.getLatitude();`

The Location class doesn't let you access these values, but I'm not sure if there's another way to do it, as it's something that seems like it should be doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Location class is a fairly simple class. Use something like this:

```
var loc = Location.Point.GetCoordinate(); 
var latitude = loc.Latitude;
var longitude = loc.Longitude;
```